# Repeatedly await asynchronous post requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, post, async-await

I want to repeatedly do a POST request, as follows:

```js
async function request(spec){
    // POST
    fetch('/spec', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            spec: spec
        })
    })
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.ok){
                console.log('POST success.');
                return;
            }
            throw new Error('POST failed.');
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
}
async function repeatRequest(times){
   for(let i=0; i<times; i++)
      await request("");
}
```

But this won't work, because I'm somehow not using asynchronous programming correctly. Somehow even after spending hours on async js I don't know if I still get it.

EDIT: this code is on the client-side.

Comment: It's unclear where your `request()` function ends, is repeatRequest supposed to be inside it? You should be returning the promise from `request()`, so `return fetch()...`. You also never provide  `spec` when calling `request`

Comment: @NickParsons the two are supposed to be separate functions

Comment: You are missing the `}` to close your request function body then...

Comment: @NickParsons oh oops. must be a copy paste mistake

Comment: Looks better, now you just need to return the promise: `return fetch()`, that way your request function will return a promise which you can await. If you want to perform your requests in parallel then you can look into using `Promise.all`

Comment: Are you trying to call `request` x times concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sequentially execute the request, you need to return the promise (return value of `fetch`) in the top level of your async function. This way the `await` keyword in the for loop will await the result of the function:

(Note that I have changed the target URL to have a running example here.)

```js
async function request(pokemon) {
  return fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokemon)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('request success.');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('request failed.');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

async function repeatRequest(times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await request("pikachu");
  }
}

repeatRequest(5);
```

Alternatively, you can use full async/await, like this:

```js
async function request(pokemon) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokemon);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('request failed.');
    }
    
    console.log('request success.');
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function repeatRequest(times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await request("pikachu");
  }
}

repeatRequest(5);
```